# SQL oder by ASC over 0, then 0

Tags: mysql

I need an SQL query that's do an ORDER ASC > 0, then = 0 at the end to the query result.
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE rank>0 ORDER BY rank ASC
and then, put at the end the ones whose rank is 0

Name       Rank
Martin     0
Bob        2
Marc       8
Mario      0
Sophia     4

After the query :
Name       Rank
Bob        2
Marc       4
Sophia     8
Martin     0
Mario      0

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
ORDER BY rank=0 ASC, rank ASC
```

The expression **`rank=0`** evaluates as a boolean expression, returns `0` for FALSE, `1` for TRUE, or `NULL`.

The more ANSI compliant equivalent syntax for `rank=0` would be:

```
CASE WHEN rank = 0 THEN 1 WHEN rank IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 0 END
```

---

Given the example data, this shows how the ordering by `rank=0` achieves the result.

```
  Name     Rank  rank=0
  -------  ----  ------
  Bob         2       0
  Sophia      4       0
  Marc        8       0
  Mario       0       1
  Martin      0       1
```

(NOTE: the order of the rows withing equal values of rank is indeterminate; there's no guarantee of the order of `Mario` and `Martin`... either way is compliant with the ORDER BY specification.)

Comment: Wouldn't `ORDER BY rank=0 ASC, rank ASC` bring the ZERO ranks at the beginning of the result set?

It should be rank=0 DESC instead?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir: no.  If `rank=0` evaluates to true, that's a integer value of 1. If `rank=0` is false, that's integer value of 0. So rows with "false" will be ordered before rows with "true". That means that rows with a value of 0 for rank will be ordered *after* rows that have a non-zero value of rank.

Comment: Cool that is interesting. Would you mind providing any link with more explanation on this phenomenon please?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir: Reference: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html). For a comparison operation, MySQL returns integer value **`1`** for TRUE, integer value **`0`** for FALSE,  or NULL. You can add an expression that does a comparison (for example `rank=0`) to the SELECT list of a query, and see what MySQL returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
SELECT *, IF(rank>0,1,0) as Ordering FROM TABLE ORDER BY Ordering DESC, rank ASC
```

You can then change the ordering with `Ordering DESC` to bring the results with ZERO rank either at the beginning or end of the result set